# How to programatically update properties on a Spring Cloud Config client

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Once you have a Spring Cloud Config Server running and serving properties to other services as expected, how can I update these properties programatically from within the application itself?

Ideally this would be handled via a REST API where a user can specify the field/value in a request body, then those values will get written to the properties file and pushed to git.

Has anyone done this before or can point me in the direction of some tutorial? Every guide I've found just has the properties get updated committed to git manually.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for same requirements, were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the use case, but just basing on the context provided, but here is some idea:

At the application instance, one thing that comes to mind is that we can trigger config refresh if we call the management API "`/actuator/refresh`". But it will load what the current values are (locally and in git repo) and not from a request body.

So my suggestion is to create your variation of this management API (let's say for example `POST /management/refresh` that will accept a request body. It will do:

1. Process the request parameters and commit to GIT repo. Use a GIT client library. Spring Cloud Config Server uses JGit for example.
2. And trigger the process that /actuator/refresh does which is mostly around [RefreshScope](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.html#refresh-java.lang.String-).

Hope it helps you.